# Windows | Uninstall script | downgrade Firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, script, uninstall, downgrade

Much like most popular browsers, Firefox wants to stay up-to-date as much as possible. In certain situations upgrading isn't the best option as a lot of stuff will probably not work with newer releases.

I want to be able to stay on Firefox 47.0 and not upgrade but there are times when the PC has a mind of it's own and does the install anyways.

Is there a way to **uninstall the current Firefox** (*and all of it's settings/preferences including user-profiles*) **and install the version of my choice**? I mean, what methods can be used to make this possible?

- using a *script* to downgrade Firefox
- installing a *program* to downgrade Firefox

Lastly, for what ever method is used it has to prioritize mobility and compatibility within Windows machines. Preferably no 3rd-party apps or anything outside of what windows has to offer.

---

### NOTE

- Firefox preferences and settings are not of any concern
- An example of the environment i'm in is that inside the directory is the (method-of-choice) + oldFireFox.exe

---

#### TAG

- firefox; ff
- uninstall; remove; delete
- previous; old; version; update
- incompatible; not working; isn't working

Comment: Have you already considered the [Firefox Extended Support Release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/) version?  It still supports additional plugins beyond Adobe Flash, and each version will be [supported for one year](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/).

Comment: Although that is a way to stay downgraded to make things work (*not sure how that's different than sticking with FF47*) when using Firefox, but it's just an alternative installer and not a script to have the current one be uninstalled and be replaced by the Extended-Support-Release version.

Comment: Yes, I know... but that's why it was posted as a question within a comment, and not submitted as an answer.  Regardless, to answer your follow-up question it is different from sticking with Firefox 47 because there isn't an Extended Support Release version of Firefox 47, so it is unavoidably destined to be upgraded after six weeks.  In contrast, the ESR version of Firefox will be supported for one year.  Just something to consider that provides compatibility and stability, but *doesn't* require a script to perform relatively simple tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox Portable App could be the right thing for you. You can use many Firefox Versions at the same time ;-)

https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Comment: That wouldn't work as it's going to make file association difficult. But since you have that link up can you find the FF v47 alternative? The one you provided is already the latest version.

Comment: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/portableapps/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Edition%2047.0/FirefoxPortable_47.0_English.paf.exe?r=&ts=1493976685&use_mirror=vorboss